# Validation in Java script for the date in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have java script in which i have to do validation for date i.e todate >= fromdate.
Below is my script. I need to validate the dates so that user will select the Fromdate-Todate. Thanks in advance.

```
// <reference path="http://localhost:5378/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />

var pubReportName = "";
```

/* Dom loaded function */

```
 $(function () {

pubReportName = "";
$("#bttnPrint").click(PrintReport_Click);

$('#txtFrDate').val('');
$('#txtToDate').val('');

$("#txtFrDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
$("#txtToDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

$('#ReportLeftDiv li').click(function () {
    // remove all active classes
    $('#ReportLeftDiv li').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

});

```
function PrintReport_Click() {



var repName = $('#ReportLeftDiv li.active').attr('id');

if (repName == undefined || repName == null) {
    alert("Please choose the Report name");
    return false;
}

var ReportParameters = new Array();
var StDt = $('#txtFrDate').val();
var EndDt = $('#txtToDate').val();

ReportParameters.push({ ReportName: "/LISReportProject/" + repName, ParaName: "pStartDate", ParaValue: StDt });
ReportParameters.push({ ReportName: "/LISReportProject/" + repName, ParaName: "pEndDate", ParaValue: EndDt });

   sessionStorage.setItem('ReportParameters', JSON.stringify(ReportParameters));
//   ShowHideProcessingDivs('SHOW');
   fnPrintResult();
   var data1 = JSON.stringify({ ReportParameters: ReportParameters });
   $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "WCF/LabStatusService.svc/SetSessionValues",
    data: data1,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processType: false,
    success: fnPrintResult,
    failure: onErrorFunction
});
```

}

```
function fnPrintResult()
 {
 $.PrintPreview("LAB Statistics Report", "../PrintPreview.aspx");
```

}

```
function onErrorFunction(result) {
//document.getElementById('divWait').style.visibility = "hidden"
//ShowHideProcessingDivs('SHOW');
PopupMessage("Error", result.d, 'Alert');
```

}

```
function ShowHideProcessingDivs(ShowHide) {
switch (ShowHide) {
    case 'SHOW':
        $('#divWait').removeClass('#overlay').addClass('').show();
        if ($('#Processing').hasClass("Processing"))
            $('#Processing').removeClass("Processing");

        $('#Processing').addClass("Processing").show();

        break;
    case 'HIDE':
        $('#divWait').hide();
        $('#Processing').hide();
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmvCU/1/)

**Javascript**

```
$('#txtFrom').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
$('#txtTo').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});

function com() {
    var start = $('#txtFrom').val();
    var to = $('#txtTo').val();
    if (new Date(to) >= new Date(start)) {
        $('#result').text("To date is greater than or equal to start");
    }else{
        $('#result').text("To date is less than to start");
    }
}
```

*There are two alternates.. Either the user might be forced to select the `to date` greater than or same as `from date` directly by using jQuery `onclosed function within datepicker` and other is by using javascript `Date` object*